# integral convergence - does this integration converge

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

i just ran into this problem and i'm having a hard time solving it:

i would like to know if this integral converges or not, and why.

*i'd prefer the normal convergence tests.*

$$
\int_2^\infty\frac{x}{\ln^3 x}dx
$$

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks,

yaron.

Comment: $\log x$ grows more slowly than $x$, so you should expect the integrand to fail to go to zero.

Comment: What are the limits of integration?

Comment: 1) the limits of the integration are from 2infinity to infinity.

Comment: 2) i know that log x grows more slowly than x, but does log^3 x too?

Comment: Those limits cannot be right.

Comment: does 2->infinity sound better?

Comment: Yes, the previous limits were definitely not correct.

Comment: okay, so lets say 2->infinity.

Comment: [W|A says](http://bit.ly/10Dn9VF) *integral does not converge*.

Comment: does x go faster to the infinity that ln^3 x?
i know that x goes faster than ln x but who sais it goes faster that kn^3 x when we approach infinity?

Comment: thanks everyone, I got it using lwhopital.

Comment: Take a look at $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{(\ln x)^p}$ for $p > 0$.  Yes, positive powers of $\ln x$ grow _really_ slowly compared to $x$.  (Ran into this in a problem I got asked about recently: this really impresses upon one this property of logarithms...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered: No, the integral does not converge, since any power of $\ln x$ grows more slowly than $x$.

Comment: Would you like to tell why it always goes smaller? (and formal proof?)

Comment: @CharlieChang: If you substitute $x=\mathrm e^y$, it says that $y$ grows more slowly than any power of $\mathrm e^y$, or equivalently (since you can transfer the power to the other side) that any power of $y$ grows more slowly than $\mathrm e^y$. This is a well-known fact about the exponential function.